# macro for typesetting and adding a line to another document

Tags: external-files, include

I am writing a lengthy document and breaking it into chapters. I would like to use something like `\include` in my `main.tex`, and that typesetting of each chapter would typeset the `main.tex` with an `\includeonly` of the specific chapter. The closest solution I know of is `subfile`, which does not satisfy me entirely for minor issues (e.g. with `minitoc`). Is there some way of coding a macro for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the basic `\include` and `\includeonly` commands are all you need, but perhaps I misunderstand.

If you create the following files and compile `main.tex` twice with the `\includeonly` line commented out, LaTeX will process the whole document and produce the table of contents with accurate page numbers.

If you then uncomment the `\includeonly` line, LaTeX will process the `main` file and `\include` only the argument to that command (in this case `ch1`). The table of contents will still reflect the page numbers of the other chapters that you previously compiled.

---

File `main.tex`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

%\includeonly{ch1} % Uncomment after first compilation

\begin{document}

\title{Your Book}
\author{Your Name}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\include{ch1}
\include{ch2}
\include{ch3}

\end{document}
```

---

File `ch1.tex`

```
\chapter{First}
\lipsum
```

---

File `ch2.tex`

```
\chapter{Second}
\lipsum
```

---

File `ch3.tex`

```
\chapter{Third}
\lipsum
```

---

### EDIT: Specify included files on the command line at the time of compilation

Another option is to define the files to be included on the command line. We define a command, `\selection` on the command line:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

% Include files specified on the command line; 
% if no files specified, include everything
\ifx\selection\undefined\relax
\else
    \includeonly{\selection}
\fi

\begin{document}

\title{Your Book}
\author{Your Name}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\include{ch1}
\include{ch2}
\include{ch3}

\end{document}
```

Then compile with this commmand:

```
pdflatex "\def\selection{ch1} \input main"
```

You could automate this with a **shell script**:

(file `latex-selection.sh`:)

```
#! /bin/sh
EXCERPT=$1
MAIN=$2
pdflatex "\\def\\selection{$EXCERPT} \\input $MAIN"
```

To include only `ch2`, invoke as `./latex-selection.sh ch2 main`.

Comment: I cannot compile the ch#.tex files here. I would like to be able to compile ch#.tex so that it compiles the main.tex with \includeonly{ch#}.

Comment: With this setup, you always compile `main`, never the included files themselves. Instead you change the `\includeonly` in `main` for the chapter you want to include.

Comment: I understand, but this is not what I want! For instance I could add
 % !TEX root = path/to/main.tex in the ch#.tex files (working with TeXShop) but I would still have to edit the \includeonly command in the main every time I work on a different chapter

Comment: I've added another option that you might find more convenient.

Comment: Thanks for this new option! It's getting close to what I want, I just have to find a way to execute this by compiling the `ch#.tex` files.

Comment: You could do this all in reverse if you extract your preamble to a separate file and the `\input` that into the chapter files (so each one has `\input main \begin{document} ... \end{document}`). I'll let someone else take it from here.